# Application Input Specification: Drawing input data of method

Tags: json, http, uml, specifications, server

Does anyone know a good way to to draw the exact structure of input data for a method? In my case I have to specify the correct input data for a server application. The server gets an http post with data. Because this data is a very complex json data structure, I want to draw this, so next developer can easily check the drawing and is able to understand, what data is needed for the http post. It would be nice if I can also draw http headers mark data as mandatory or nice to have.

I dont need a data flow diagramm or sth. like that. What I need is a drawing, how to build a valid json for the server method.

Please if anyone have an idea, just answer or comment this question, even if you just have ideas for buzz words, I can google myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to describe data structure consider **(1)** using the [UML class diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html) with multiplicities and ownership and "named association ends". Kirill Fakhroutdinov's examples [uml-diagrams.org: Online Shopping](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/online-shopping-domain-uml-diagram-example.html) and [uml-diagrams.org: Sentinel HASP Licensing Domain](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-licensing-domain-diagram-example.html) illustrate what your drawing might look like.

As you need to specifically describe `json` structure then **(2)** Google: "json schema" to see how others approached the same problem.

Personally, besides providing the UML diagram I'd **(3)** consider writing a [TypeScript definition file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files-examples) which actually can describe `json` structure including simple types, nested structures, optional parts etc. and moreover the next developer can validate examples of data structures (unit tests) against the definition by writing a simple `TypeScript` script and trying to compile it

Comment: I agree, but always name those association ends! See the metamodel in the UML spec for examples of how to name them so they at least hint at your intended semantics.